# AOP in Kotlin to be used in Java class

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8, aop

I´m implementing a library in Kotlin that it will be used from Java.
It would be possible to create an annotation and AOP code in Kotlin, and then being used from Java.+

If that possible a documentation or example it would be awesome. I cannot find anything with that interoperability.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the annotation, there should not be any problem implementing it in Kotlin.

As for the aspect, when compiled with the Kotlin compiler it shall end up being a regular JVM class with all the necessary @AspectJ annotations, but it will not be an aspect because it was not compiled by the AspectJ compiler which as of today only understands Java source code.

- If you use such an "unfinished" aspect via LTW (load-time weaving), the AspectJ weaver can finish it into an aspect while it is being loaded, so that scenario should work.
- In the case of trying to use the unfinished aspect for compile-time or binary weaving against Java (or Kotlin) target classes, an intermediate step to finish the unfinished aspect using the AspectJ compiler would be necessary, but I never tried that and do not know if it is even possible. It would be interesting to try. I do not speak Kotlin, but maybe it would be fun to try if you have something for me to start with like a sample project, ideally built with Maven. If there is any way to pull this off, we would end up using the AspectJ Maven plugin for just like @dreamcrash suggested, just in a different way.

BTW, I need more information from you about what you mean by "use from Java". Please elaborate.

---

**Update:** I just gave it a quick try:

- Annotation + aspect both in Kotlin
- Compile with Kotlin compiler into *my-aspect.jar*, *aspectjrt.jar* on the class path
- Package Kotlin classes into a JAR
- Java class using annotation from Kotlin aspect JAR
- Compile with *ajc*, *my-aspect.jar* on the inpath and *aspectjrt.jar* and *kotlin-stdlib.jar* on the class path.
- Result is e.g. in *bin* directory, both the Java class and the two Kotlin classes from the JAR, but the aspect this time finished by *ajc* (bigger class file than original).
- Run Java program with *bin* folder, *aspectjrt.jar* and *kotlin-stdlib.jar* on the class path.

**Works nicely, aspect kicks in.**

The only step remaining is to "mavenise" this in connection with AspectJ Maven plugin, which should be fairly easy. But the answer to your question is: **Yes, you can implement an aspect in Kotlin and use it combined with Java target classes.** The downside of course is that you need the Kotlin standard library on the class path, not just the AspectJ runtime as usual.

---

**Update 2:** I created a Maven multi-module playground project for myself and for your convenience. Just clone my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_AspectImplementedInKotlin_65413567), then build and run according to the read-me file.

Comment: **Update:** I tried, it works. See my updated answer.

Comment: @dreamcrash: I might have been too quick to dismiss your link to [this blog post](https://zemke.io/aspectj-kotlin). The thing is that there the usage scenario is not described, there is only the AspectJ Maven XML snippet. I have not tried yet, but after what I just did manually on the command line, I think the Maven version of what I just did might look similar to what is shown there. That really depends on the project setup, though, e.g. if aspect and target classes are in the same or different modules. My test was two separate modules and that is not covered on that website.

Comment: **Update 2:** I created a Maven multi-module playground project for myself and for your convenience. Just clone my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_AspectImplementedInKotlin_65413567), then build and run according to the read-me file.